# USB mouse with the pointer direction reversed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse

So my USB mouse is with some kind of problem such that the pointer moves in the opposite direction of the direction that I drag it.

Comment: Documented as a bug; please add to the report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1800634 and then boot from a LiveUSB and see if the problem persists. Once you've tested it from a LiveUSB, then come back here and let us know what happened. Please click [edit] to add your report to your question; please do not use Add Comment, but use [edit] instead.

Comment: have you tried rotating the screen in Display properties to see what happens?